# Python: Rodeo does not star

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, rodeo

I have tried to install the latest version `Rodeo 2.3.2.dmg` but it does not startup and I get the following error

[image]

I have installed `anaconda 2.7` and I can run Python from command prompt. If I click on `I USE A DIFFERENT COMMAND FOR PYTHON` and enter `ipython`, then it starts but nothing happens if I enter a command such as `x = 2`.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `python`

Comment: Yes. That didn't work.